# Clickhouse query to assign settings profile to user or role

Tags: sql, database, clickhouse

I have a settings profile already created on my cluster. How do I assign this to an existing user or role? I only see create query in the official [documentation](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/settings-profile).

Answer (score 0):

You can assign settings to a user via a command like this:

```
ALTER USER 'myUsername' SETTINGS join_algorithm='grace_hash';
```

If you have previous settings or other settings, you need to be careful to assign them all in this statement, as it will overwrite previously defined settings:

```
ALTER USER 'myUsername' SETTINGS join_algorithm='grace_hash', max_threads=32;
```

Can view settings assigned in this SHOW CREATE USER:

```
SHOW CREATE USER 'myUsername';
```

Similar for ROLE:

```
SHOW CREATE ROLE 'myRole';
```

Related links:

- https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/user
- https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/role